# Using the custom config file in UAA

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa

I am trying to setup a forked version of cloud-foundry uaa (version 3.2.1). As per the document I need to set the variable `CLOUD_FOUNDRY_CONFIG_PATH` for the build to use my custom `uaa.yml` file.

I tried setting up the environment variable `CLOUD_FOUNDRY_CONFIG_PATH` in `.bash_profile` as well as tried doing the build in the below way,

```
./gradlew -DCLOUD_FOUNDRY_CONFIG_PATH=<my_config_file_parent> run
```

But none of them picked up my custom `uaa.yml` . Any help on this would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [README.md](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/README.md), you should set your configuration in the file `<my_config_file_parent>/uaa.yml` and set the environment variable `CLOUD_FOUNDRY_CONFIG_PATH`.

In order to start the uaa with your customization, you could use:

```
CLOUD_FOUNDRY_CONFIG_PATH=<my_config_file_parent> ./gradlew run
```

I tried this with release 4.8.3 and also with 3.20.1 and it works (I did not find any 3.2.1?)